# BurpSuite window contents do not resize when using BSPWM as tiling manager

Tags: window, size

I currently use BSPWM as a tiling manager, it works mostly fine. However, when I try to resize a BurpSuiteCommunity window I am unable to get the BurpSuiteCommunity window to properly adjust the size of its contents.

This is what the BurpSuite window looks like when floating:
[image: BurpSuite Window Mode]

This is what the BurpSuite window looks like when stretched (fails to stretch contents as well):

[image: BurpSuite Window stretched with BSPWM]

Relevant Facts:

https://pastebin.com/6F5KUvTq -->  ~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc file (configuration file for keyboard shortcut manager sxhkd (https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd))

https://pastebin.com/2b1zMrki --> ~/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc file (configuration file for bspwm - tiling window manager (https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm))

This issue persists across different versions of BurpSuite.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue:

add WMNAME LG3D &
[image]

Pre-requisites:

make sure WMNAME is installed in your system.

**sudo apt install wmname -y --> install wmname**

**which wmname --> verify**